# Sound on spotify not heard when entering a call

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, spotify

so I've been using ubuntu 20.04 and when I'm listening to spotify and I join a call in Microsoft Teams as example, it automatically turns off spotify volume and I have to open config to turn on the volume
How can I solve this so it won't turn off?

Answer (score 0):

Pulse Audio has a corking mode that mutes spotify and other music apps when engaged in telephony.  You can disable it by finding the `load-module module-role-cork` in a config file and commenting it out.

I found this line in /etc/pulse/default.pa

I commented it out, did a pulse audio -k and now I can spotify while on Teams!